# How to fix Tab Activity action bar up color in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabactivity

Above action bar, white color is displaying. I want to fix that one. Please check
attached image file.

Thanks in Advance [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbZuV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#39bf96"));
    }
```

Comment: what if i want to hide the status bar ?

Comment: You will need to set the theme to Fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

However if you want to hide those `Action Bar` or `Status Bar`, this would help

add this line into your `style` resources file.

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and then make sure you change the `theme` in your `AndroidManifest` file.

**Example**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/mainPageName" //Your Activity Name
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> //Change HERE
</activity>
```

Comment: It's not what the OP have asked.